# Struts2, best practice for using method={1}

Tags: java, xml, struts2, struts

I'm new to Struts 2 and I've come across this syntax (recommended in the tutorial).

```
<action name="Register_*" method="{1}" class="Register">
    <result name="input">/member/Register.jsp</result>
    <result type="redirectAction">Menu</result>
</action>
```

I understand that it calls Register.{1} method. The problem is a user could put in another (random) value and cause a 500 error (which would correctly be logged as an error).

How can this be prevented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all it won't call the Register.{1} method. It would call Register_{1} where {1} might be an action type (usually edit, show e.t.c)

Meaning that the URL is actually

```
Register_View
Register_Edit
e.t.c.
```

So if a user manually changes the URL to something that is not there such as

```
Register_methodThatDoesNotExist
```

then struts 2 will return an error.

But why is this a problem? In any web application that uses any technology if the user tampers manually with the URL an error will be returned (also the 404)

What are you trying to prevent exactly?

**Update:**

To prevent 500 errors you can catch all actions (that do not match any rule) and redirect them in an error page.
See the "Wildcard Default" default paragraph at the struts 2 wiki

http://cwiki.apache.org/WW/action-configuration.html

This **must** be at the end of the struts configuration

Comment: Register_invalidMethod.action returns a 500 error, not a 404. java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:Register.invalidMethod()

I would like to try to prevent any "500" internal errors being triggered by something like an invalid URL.

I don't see how this syntax can be used in any serious web application.

Comment: Read some more about wildcards in struts documentation. There are many neat tricks that do a lot of things including what you want.

Comment: The problem is, it does match the first wildcard and hence will fall through to a 500 error. Do you think it's best to avoid this syntax altogether?

Comment: Well the wildcard is only useful if you have 4-5 type of actions (e.g add, view, delete, archive, delete). If you have 1 or 2 then you can just hardcode the names and avoid the wildcard all together (and catching everything else with the global rule at the bottom).

Comment: You also catch 500 errors at the application server level if that really concerns you.

Answer (score 8):

In my applications we use it like this:

```
  <action name="*/*" class="{1}Action" method="{2}">
       <interceptor-ref name="CustomAuthStack" />       
            <result>/pages/{1}/{2}.jsp</result>
            <result name="input">/pages/error/denied.jsp</result>
            <result name="logout">/pages/error/denied.jsp</result>

            <!-- methods that come back to listing after processing -->
            <result name="remove" type="redirectAction">{1}/list</result>
            <result name="save"   type="redirectAction">{1}/list</result>
            <result name="enable"   type="redirectAction">{1}/list</result>

   ....

   </action>
```

for slashes in action like myapp/users/list you must enable slashes in action with the

```
<constant name="struts.enable.SlashesInActionNames" value="true" />
```

in the strus.xml.

so now you have a standard:

action -->  UserAction
jsp ----->  users/list.jsp

etc.

Comment: This looks nice, but didn't work for me as Struts2 is always interpreting the * before the slash as a namespace and interprets the second * as the target action.