# What is the meaning of method = "{1}" in action configuration?

Tags: java, struts, struts-config

There is a project download from network, in its `structs.xml`, there is action configuration:

```
<action name="elecMenuAction_*" class="elecMenuAction" method="{1}">
    <result name="menuHome">/WEB-INF/page/menu/home.jsp</result>
</action>
```

I don't know the `method="{1}"` mean, how to understand the mean?

Answer (score 1):

This link can be useful in understanding the above syntax
[Struts2, best practice for using method={1}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729885/struts2-best-practice-for-using-method-1)

Answer (score 1):

If there is `method="{number}"`, corresponding， the action config should  have `*` in its name,

Example:

```
<action name="user_*" class="UserAction" method="{1}">
```

and in its corresponding jsp if has a form :

In that way, structs will let the `user_userLogin`  action according to the `user_*`’s format analysis, and take out the `*` according the number `1, 2, 3 …`, `1` means the first `*`.

If the action config like this:

```
<action name="user_*_*" class="com.xyz.{1}Action" method="{2}">
```

and the jsp form is like this:

```
<form action="user_Login_userLogin" method="post">
```

Its action will become like this:

```
class="com.xyz.Login" method="{userLogin}"
```